# birkas hagomel: based on the toda?

Tags: blessing, korban, hagomel

Is *birkas hagomel* based on the *korban toda*? [*B'rachos* 54:2](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=106&size=1) seems to derive it from *p'sukim* without reference to the *toda*; *Rambam* puts one in *Maase Hakorbanos* and the other in *B'rachos* without any mention in either place of the other rite. Yet I seem to recall that there's a connection between them: does anyone know whether there is one and what it is?

Comment: "_Rambam puts one in Maase Hakorbanos and the other in B'rachos_ ..." 'One' and 'other' what? Also, can you cite specific places (especially the _Ma'aseh ha-Qorbanot_ one)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the times of the Beis HaMikdash, a person who survived a potentially life-threatening situation brought a Korban Todah, to express his gratitude to Hashem. (Vayikra 7:12 Rashi and Rashbam)

Nowadays, when we no longer have the Beis HaMikdash and Korbonos cannot be brought on the altar, we substitute Birchas HaGomel a public proclamation of gratitude to Hashem for an offering. (Rosh, Berachos 9:3, [Chasam Sofer Orach Chaim 51](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=794&st=&pgnum=39&hilite=) and [Avnei Nezer Orach Chaim 39](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1344&st=&pgnum=65&hilite=))