# causeless hagomel

Tags: blessing, korban, hagomel

*Rambam*, *Maase Hakorbanos* [9:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%98_%D7%94), indicates that a *toda* is just another kind of *sh'lamim*. In [*perek* 14](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%99%D7%93) he mentions that a *sh'lamim* needs no special circumstances, as opposed to a *chatas* which can only be brought if one needs to bring one. That is, one can bring a *toda* whenever he wants.

(This is reflected in the little "*y'hi ratzon*" prayers we say during *Ezehu m'koman*: the *chatas* prayer says (paraphrasing) "if I must bring a *chatas*, this prayer should count as if I've brought one" whereas the *toda* prayer says (paraphrasing again) merely "this prayer should count as if I've brought one".)

[*Birkas hagomel* is in lieu of the *toda*.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8426)

Yet *birkas hagomel* can, apparently, not be said whenever one wants. *Shulchan Aruch* and *Mishna B'rura* 219 carefully delineate under what circumstances one says it, and imply that under other circumstances one does not. (To be sure, there are circumstances about which the *halacha* is not clear, and, therefore, might indicate that someone "can" say the *b'racha*. But that's not comparable to the *toda*, which anyone can bring even without halachically accepted cause.)

So my first question is why. That is: If *hagomel* is based on the *toda*, why can the latter be brought whenever one wants and the former not?

My second question is whether anyone actually holds that *hagomel can* be said without halachically accepted cause.

Comment: Or: "Is the prohibition of Lo Tisa more strict that the prohibition of chulin on the Mizbeyach?"?

Comment: @IsaacMoses - It's not necessarily clear that "lo sisa" is a real concern in the case of unnecessary _b'rachos_. See, for example the Ra"sh on [Kidushin 30b](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%90), commenting on the opinion of Rabenu Tam in _Tosafos_ s.v. "_d'lo_". (Anyone know a good linkable text of the Ra"sh)?

Comment: For future questions and thoughts... I would suggest that when something is 'based on' it does not mean 'the same as'.  When its different its good to ask why its different, but the word "if" in your question seems odd, it should be 'since'. I.e. no analogy is perfect. ... to put it differently, this difference between todah and gomel is no reason to suspect that Gomel is not based on the Todah.

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/93751/170

Comment: @WAF I think you mean this ([§49](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14313&st=&pgnum=175)).

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/118361/170

Answer (score 4):

Speculation:

It could be that the Sages weren't comfortable with innovating a beracha with unlimited scope, given the problems with unnecessarily invoking God's name. The Torah had [infinitely] more authority to create such an open-ended option, even for something as serious as a korban.

Comment: Maybe. But consider [OC 222:1–2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14164&st=&pgnum=260&hilite=).

Comment: @msh210 Good point. It seems, though, that Shehecheyanu and Hatov Vehametiv are said without God's name, though Dayan Ha-emet is said with it. This seems to be partial support for my idea that Chazal were uncomfortable with open-ended berachot that invoke God's name, particularly if there's a special reason why Dayan Ha-emet would be an exception.

Comment: @msh210 , IsaacMoses :  See the Magen Avraham OC 223 sk 4

Answer (score 3):

One could say that even though the blessing is based on a korban, not all the rules were transferred, for example, shacharis and mincha were made instead of the korban tamid, yet one couldn't bring a "stam" tamid yet one can pray a nedavah.

Comment: It's interesting that your example is in a way the inverse of the one in the question. But yours has a bunch more complicating factors, primary among which is the dual basis of regular _t'fila_. It is natural that the parameters of the resulting practice would not be limited to the parameters of only one of the causes (_t'midin_ and not _avos_).