# Why say birchat gomel with a minyan?

Tags: halacha, minyan, hagomel

[Birchat ha gomel is said in place of bringing a toda korban.](/q/8426)  Why is the birchat gomel said with a minyan?  Why do we want to with a minyan to say birchat hagomel?  Did a toda require a minyan?

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8427/170

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam ([MT Brachot 10:8](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/927678/jewish/Berachot-Chapter-Ten.htm)) links the recitation of Birkat Hagomel in front of 10 people to a verse in *Tehilim*

> These thanks must be rendered in the presence of ten people, of whom
>   two are sages, **as implied by [Psalms 107:32](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.107.32?lang=bi): "They will exalt Him in
>   the congregation of the people and they will praise Him in the seat of
>   the elders."**

and so writes the [Shulchan Aruch OC 219:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.219.3?lang=bi) and [Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 61:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.61.2?lang=bi)

For a much more involved discussion see [here](http://www.jewishpress.com/judaism/ask-the-rabbi/q-a-birkat-hagomel-part-viii-2/2014/07/17/) from R Yaakov Klass

Comment: The Talmud (Berachos 54b) cites the verse in Psalms as well.