# Can one bring a Korban Todah as a nedava if he is not from the 4 who must give thanks?

Tags: korban

As the title says, must one be from the four who need to give thanks (edit—[Brachos 54b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.54b.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) to bring a todah and the associated 40 chalos or can you bring it as a nedava without being from the four?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8427/170

Answer (score 1):

מדברי רש"י אלו נראה שאין חובה להקריב קרבן תודה, אלא אם נדר מרצונו לאחר הצלתו, וכך הבינו כמה אחרונים בדעתו.[3] **אולם מדבריו על פסוק טז נראה שקרבן תודה אינו בא בנדר או בנדבה**,[4] ומפירוש רש"י לגמרא מנחות[5] נראה שעצם הנס מחייב הבאת תודה.[6] כך גם משמע מדברי ה'אבן עזרא',[7] אלא שמדבריו משמע שהחיוב רק על החולה. רבנו בחיי כותב (ויקרא ו, ב) כך:
נראה שלדעת הרמב"ם קרבן תודה – כשמו כן הוא, ומביאו כל אדם הרוצה להביע תודתו לה' על שמחה או הצלה מיוחדת, וכן נראה בדברי הגמרא (תענית יט ע"א) שחוני המעגל הביא פר הודאה לאחר ירידת הגשמים.[10]

לסיכום: א. לרש"י ועוד ראשונים יש להביא קרבן תודה כהודאה על נס הצלה מצרה. אחרים אומרים שקרבן תודה מובא גם על שמחה גדולה (רבנו בחיי) או כשרוצה לשוב ולהתוודות מחטאיו (רד"ק). **לרמב"ם נראה שיכול להביאו כרצונו בעת שרוצה להודות לה**'.
http://tiny.cc/cru1tz

I should mention in the morning we do say c'ilu hikravti todah. So it seems you can. I now notice the [likutai mahrich](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33006&st=&pgnum=153) says the SA says you can. Although the SA does not mention it..

To summarise the first sefer I mentioned says according to **Rashi one can't and Rambam perhaps can.** (I don't think the Rambam means that you can, only if he has some simcha not everyday).
The second sefer says **one can and we do every day say so.**

Comment: Also as far as formatting, the big links can appear a bit messy. If you highlight any given word/s you turn them into a hyperlinks which makes the answer a bit easier on the eye.

Comment: I made the second link work into your answer - this is what I meant when I said turn it into a hyperlink so no links need be listed in the actual answer. If you click on 'edit' on the answer you can see how it is done. Hatzlocho!

Comment: @Dov Thanks! Thanks!

Comment: The diyuk from Rashi on v. 16 seems a bit weak, and in fact Mizrachi there says precisely the opposite: פי' הא דכתיב ואם נדר או נדבה לאו למימרא דהא דכתיב לעיל אם על תודה לאו נדר או נדבה הוא דתודה נמי באה בנדר ובנדבה היא שאם אמר הרי עלי תודה הרי הוא נדר ואם אמר הרי זו תודה הרי הוא נדבה. (And anyway, the diyuk at most might be that for a nes there's a chiyuv to bring a todah, but not that you can't bring one otherwise.) There's also Zevachim 81b, which says pretty explicitly מרבה אני תודה ושלמים שבאין בנדר ונדבה.

Comment: @Meir. That diyuk is not my work. But my question stays. Why doesnt the SA mention it in OC chapter one together with olah and shlomim.