# Can you say the Birkas Hagomel on Shabbos or Pesach?

Tags: shabbat, passover, korban, chametz-leaven, hagomel

[We do not say “Mizmor LeSodoh”](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%9E%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94)  on those days when a Korban Todah could not be brought.

So we do not say it on Shabbos or Yom Tov because you could not bring individual offerings on those days and we do not say it on Erev Pesach or Chol HaMoed Pesach because it contains Chometz. Nor do we say it on Yom Kippur and Erev Yom Kippur.

The blessing for deliverance from danger (Birkas Hagomel) was instituted, according to many authorities [instead of the  Korban Todah](https://daf-yomi.com/Data/UploadedFiles/DY_Item/18866-sFile.pdf) 
ברכת הגומל במקום קרבן תודה איתקן

and see related [birkas hagomel: based on the toda?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8424/birkas-hagomel-based-on-the-toda)

Can the  Birkas Hagomel be said when the  Korban Todah could not be brought? I have certainly heard it on Shabbos!

Comment: Ask about Yom Kippur and Erev Yom Kippur also - we don’t say Mizmor LeSodah then, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to your question is clearly yes, as you have noted, all of Kelal Yisrael says it on Shabbos.

Sources can be found [here](http://ph.yhb.org.il/plus/10-16-03/) as to whether it can be said at night, based on the same potential issue (can't bring a Todah at night), and Rav Eliezer Melamed notes:

> ובפתח הדביר ריט, יב, דחה את סברת השדה יצחק, **כי אין ללמוד מכללי הקרבנות לברכת 'הגומל', שהיא איננה ממש במקום קרבן תודה.**‏

Answer (score 2):

The Rosh (Berachos Ch. 9) writes that the blessing of Hagomel was instituted in the place of Korban Todah.

Chasam Sofer (Responsa #51) cites an opinion (*Sdeh Yitzchok, Berachos*) that therefore Hagomel may not be said at night, like Korban Todah was not sacrificed at night. Chasam Sofer disagrees (the obligation to express thanks through blessing was instituted in place of Korban, but it isn't a form of sacrifice which has time constraints).

Maharam Shik (Responsa 86) indeed asks that according to the opinion that it isn't said at night, it should also be forbidden to say on Shabbos.